# Django Forms saving request.user in ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a simple Group model that users  can be added.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
             settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
             related_name='admin_on_group')

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modifies = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have a basic `CreateView` for the group. The logged in user who creates the group get saved in the field `created_by`.  I however ALSO want to save the same logged in user in the field `users` so that he can participate as a normal member of the group. The problem is that the view ends up ONLY saving the logged in user and the other users passed in from the form field `users` are not saved.

For example, If a user called 'george' creates a group, he should be added in the `created_by` and `users` as well. As of now, when I select other users in the form, only george gets saved in both fields.

```
class GroupCreateView(CreateView):

    form_class = GroupForm
    template_name = "groups/group_create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.created_by = self.request.user

        form.save()

        # Apparently you can only add M2M relationships saves after first            
        # saving
        form.users.add(User.objects.get(pk = self.request.user.pk))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('group_list'))

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(GroupCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user

        return kwargs
```

I have a modelForm that has the following outline.
Note: The initial data passed in the `self.fields['users']` below also doesn't show. I have also used a custom model that has phone_number as the USERNAME_FIELD. The querysets passed in the `self.fields['users']` works.

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()


class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'users', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # popping the user from kwargs dictionary that has been 
        # passed in CreateView
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

        self.user = user  # setting self.user to be equal to user above

        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['users'] = UserModelChoiceField(
               queryset=User.objects.exclude(phone_number=str(user)),
               initial=User.objects.get(phone_number=str(user))
        )
```

Comment: i guess you need to call save again after adding the user.
mygroup=form.save()   
mygroup.users.add(User.objects.get(pk = self.request.user.pk))   
mygroup.save()

Comment: Note, there's no point doing that additional query for `User.objects.get(pk = self.request.user.pk)`. Just use `self.request.user` like you have already: `form.users.add(self.request.user)`.

Comment: Another suggestion to improve the code - I would use `queryset=User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk)` because filtering using `str(user)` is fragile. There's no point using `initial=User.objects.get(phone_number=str(user))`, since that user is excluded from the queryset so won't be an option in the form. If you do set `initial` to something else, I think it should be a list, since it's a multiple choice field (I'm not 100% sure about that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've [saved the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) with `commit=False`, you need to call the form's `save_m2m()` method to save the many-to-many data after you have saved the instance.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.created_by = self.request.user
    instance.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    # Apparently you can only add M2M relationships saves after first            
    # saving
    instance.users.add(self.request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('group_list'))
```

Note that I've changed the line to `instance = form.save(commit=False)` to make it clearer that `save()` returns an instance, and so that you still have access to the form.

Comment: Thanks!!! That solves the problem of save. I will try to get material to understand why I should use instance and why I should save instances to the M2M relationships after saving the other ForiegnKey relationships. I even do not need the initial value of user in the  form field. THANKS!

Comment: As I said above, your initial data doesn't make sense -- you've excluded that user from the queryset.